I create a selfdefine runtime module for unreal engine, but it does not startup
I create a new module in directory Engine/Source/Runtime/MyModule, and create MyModule.Build.cs, MyModule.cpp.
In MyModule.Build.cs, I write:

using UnrealBuildTool;

public class MyModule: ModuleRules
{
    public MyModule(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        bUseUnity = false;
        
        PCHUsage = ModuleRules.PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;
        
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(
            new string[]
            {
                "Core",
                "Eigen",
            }
        );
            
        
        PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(
            new string[]
            {
            }
        );

        DynamicallyLoadedModuleNames.AddRange(
            new string[]
            {
                // ... add any modules that your module loads dynamically here ...
            }
        );

        PrivateDefinitions.AddRange(
            new string[]
            {
                
            }
        );

        UnsafeTypeCastWarningLevel = WarningLevel.Off;
        ShadowVariableWarningLevel = WarningLevel.Off;

        CppStandard = CppStandardVersion.Cpp17;
    }
}

And in MyModule.cpp, I write:
#include "Modules/ModuleInterface.h"
#include "Modules/ModuleManager.h"
#define LOCTEXT_NAMESPACE "MyModule"

class FMyModule: public IModuleInterface
{

public:
    FMyModule()
    {
    }


    // IModuleInterface interface
    virtual void StartupModule() override
    {
        // Do something
    }

    virtual void ShutdownModule() override
    {

    }

};

In my understanding, the modules in Engine/Source/Runtime are loaded defaultly, but it seems that, when I open an project, the FMyModule::StartupModule() is not called.

You should create a Plugin and put your module in it instead. This is exactly what they exist for. Engine modules are only built when you build the Engine, C++ is a compiled language, you can't just drop files in a folder and expect them to be run.

Thank you. I put this module in runtime because some engine modules depend on it. I finally solve this problem by load it with other engine module. @DatGeoudon
